# ftp outbound channel adapter can give success after file completes ftp?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to know if there was a way to get success after the ftp has completed. I have a file that gets copied properly to the ftp folder but the filenamegenerator bean is called before the actual copying is started. Since size, network speed etc can cause delay, I would like to know after the ftp finishes...

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

See the [retry-and-more sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) it shows how to use an [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) to take different actions based on success/failure.